# Floating of steel plate in water

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics

Consider a steel plate, in which orientation will it float in water 'horizontal or vertical' ?
According to me in horizontal orientation plate will float but in vertical orientation it will not float because center of gravity will be above center of buoyancy so it is in unstable equilibrium. Am I correct ?

Comment: The relationship between the center of gravity of some object and the center of buoyancy of the same does _not_ tell you whether the object will float or sink. What it tells you is whether the object will roll over _if_ and when it floats. You may have seen diagrams in which the "object" is a boat. But boats have a way of filling with water and sinking when they turn up-side down. That has nothing to do with center-of-anything: The boat sinks because it fills with water when it turns over.

Comment: For a closed object, that cannot fill with water the only thing that determines whether it will float or sink is whether or not its density is less than, or greater than the density of the fluid that you want to float it in.

Comment: @SolomonSlow so steel plate will not float in both the orientations?

Comment: "Steel plate" sounds like you are talking about a solid slab of metal. Why do you expect that solid steel would float in water in _any_ orientation?

Comment: @SolomonSlow Yes I am referring to a solid slab of steel, I think it should float in horizontal orientation

Comment: I don't think steel will float on water. Imagine an object floating in water. Imagine you can freeze the water and then remove the object. That leaves a hole in the ice. If the object truly was floating, then the amount of water that would fill that hole (a.k.a., the amount of water _displaced_ by the object) would weigh exactly the same as the object itself. But a _solid_ steel object always weighs more than the amount of water it could displace. It is more _dense_ than water. It always will sink, no matter which way you orient it.

Comment: @SolomonSlow If thickness of steel slab is very less, then can it float due to surface tension ?

Comment: @Max  In order for something to float, its density must be less than the density of the fluid. The density of steel is about 8 g/cm$^3$ vs 1 g/cm$^3$ of water so no way it will float.  Moreover, the thickness of the steel is irrelevant since its density doesn't change with shape.  Simply say the plate is made of material less dense than water. The exact density doesn't matter since your question has to do with stability.

Comment: @Max, I have seen a demo in which a clean, steel sewing needle  rested on the surface of clean water without breaking the surface tension, but that's not what "floating" usually means because the force that supported the needle was not [_buoyancy_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buoyancy).

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...Let me guess what you are thinking.

A steel plate would have negligible thickness. So, in horizontal orientation, pressure on both surfaces would be equal. Hence no buoyant force.
(Or are you thinking something else)

This explanation is totally wrong.
First, there is not a thing that exists without all the 3 dimensions. So,  considering the thickness zero would be wrong.
Also, even if buoyant force is zero, it must surely have mass. So, gravity would call it.

Actually, it has very small mass, hence small weight. There is small pressure difference, hence small buoyant force. And this small weight would be greater than the small buoyant force.

So, steel plate will sink in any orientation. After sinking, considering the plate to be uniform, the center of gravity and center of buoyancy will become same. Hence no torque.